# iOS: Unit Testing for Sqlite

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing

Please help me answer this question: should i write unit testing for data access that interact with local database of iOS app, in this case is SQLite database. If should, how can i write them? use mock up or use db file.

Comment: why do you want to work with SQLite? the last official support for the raw SQLite in iOS from the Apple was in the iO2; you should rather use the `CoreData`, `plist`s or any serialisable objects instead...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to test your program's logic and not just the ability to access SQLite, a test double (either a mock object or a dummy object) will give you test that's somewhat easier to maintain than a separate db file.  A separate db file has to have the right data in the right rows, and if you modify it in one test you have to reset it before the next. If your test data gets out of sync, your tests will start to fail.  A mock object with literal test values will never get out of sync.

Using a mock will pretty much force you to use dependency injection so you can substitute it in for the real data object.  Using a db file will not force you to use dependency injection.  So if you're working with a lot of existing code that doesn't follow the DI pattern, a db file would be the "easy" choice, although not the best choice from an object oriented perspective.

Comment: You can easily provide a "canned" DB (constructed on a desktop if you wish) and repeatedly copy it into the "live" DB location to reset for the next test.  Much more realistic than a "mock" object.

Comment: @HotLicks, that approach obscures the intent of the unit test, because he needs an external tool to edit the .pdb files. He can't just look at his test code and see the values directly.  It's not readable.  Remember, at this point he doesn't need to test the .pdb files, he needs to test a module's logic.  Separate .pdb files is a great approach for system testing, but not so much for unit testing.

Comment: To each his own, I suppose.  But the testing will be a lot more robust with a real database (that responds like a real one).  And it will go faster, so testers will be less tempted to only do ten variations.

Comment: @HotLicks, that's a great way to do robust feature testing, behaviour testing, system testing, and/or integration testing.  There is nothing wrong with using test files for those activities.  But the question was about unit testing.  And unit testing is about white-box testing the logic of one specific module at a time, not whole program functionality all at once.

Comment: But if you have to program each response into your "mock object", you've got a strong incentive to only do a handful of variations, skipping boundary conditions, et al.  (One ignores such incentives at great peril.)  With a test DB it's easy to load up data for 20-30-100 different variations.  You also know the DB will be responding accurately.  The one situation where the "mock object" may be worthwhile is in simulating error conditions -- DB locked, DB offline/not found, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've done this by creating a new SQLite DB file for each test case.  In the test cases I would test that my code writes to the DB and reads the exact same thing that was written to it.  This way all the test data is in the code so the test cases are clearer.

This approach sacrifices speed but my unit tests still ran pretty fast.